# Node Express: how to only send custom error messages back to client

Tags: node.js, express

How can i ensure that only error messages that i create are sent to the client, in the context of a promise rejection?

I'm throwing a custom error, which is working fine.

```
return db.query(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE hostId = ? AND status = ?;`,[userId, ACTIVE_EVENT])
.then((results)=>{
    if(results.length != 0)
        throw new Error('You already have an active event')
})
```

It's later being caught

```
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(400).send(err.message)
});
```

And a nice error msg goes to the client.

But sometimes i get a nasty error from a malformed database query, or whatever, and the client would see a msg like "ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect time value:"

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce your custom error object, like this guy did:
[Node.js custom error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091291/node-js-custom-error-handling)

Then throw instances of your custom error when needed. And only add the message to the response if the error is an instance of your custom error.

e.g.

```
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
    if (err instanceof CustomError) {
        res.status(400).send(err.message)
    }
});
```